# Looking for a better solution to scrape multiple webpages with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, datetime, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the results of sports game off a website. The website has all the results of all the games which is perfect, but they are on many pages. Each page represents one day and I am gathering data over many months of games so it will be quite a lot of urls to enter.

The way I set it up now is that i have a base url, and a list of the dates that I can append using a for loop. This way works fine, but I was curious if there was a better way before I enter the many many dates I will be scraping over.

```
    url = 'http://www.url.com?'

    #this list would hold hundreds of dates
    dates = ['month=11&day=1&year=2016', 'month=11&day=2&year=2016', ...]

    for i in dates:
        page = requests.get(url+i)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    #and so on, this part works as intended
```

Comment: I mean, what you have looks already ok. What is the thing that bothers you with your current implementation? There are few improvements that can be done to improve the readability of the code, but it's not that essential. What's bothering you with your current implementation?

Comment: Whats bothering me is that I would have to manually enter hundreds of dates into the date list. I was just wondering if their was a more efficient way around that, If not then I would do it.

any other tips for improvement would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, you are only interested in specific dates right? Do you have some constrains on the dates? Because you could automate the creation of the dates but I am not sure if you want to do this.

Comment: The dates have to be in the format of the dates list. As long as there isnt an obvious solution to automate this, I dont mind entering them. I just didnt want to do it this way if it would be considered bad practice.

Comment: Does the pages have some references to where the next page is, like a "next issue" link or something?

Comment: Yeah there is a next button on the page

Answer (score 0):

If you really wish to search on every single day, then `datetime` and `timedelta` can be used to iterate over all the possible days. Give it a starting date, this can then be advanced one day at a time until an end date (which could be `datetime.now()` for today):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

base_url = "http://www.url.com?month={}&day={}&year={}"

search_date = datetime(2016, 11, 1)
end_date = datetime(2017, 1, 1)
one_day = timedelta(days=1)

while search_date < end_date:
    url = base_url.format(search_date.month, search_date.day, search_date.year)
    print(url)

    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    search_date += one_day
```

This would give you something like:

```
http://www.url.com?month=11&day=1&year=2016
http://www.url.com?month=11&day=2&year=2016
http://www.url.com?month=11&day=3&year=2016
http://www.url.com?month=11&day=4&year=2016
.
.
.
http://www.url.com?month=12&day=29&year=2016
http://www.url.com?month=12&day=30&year=2016
http://www.url.com?month=12&day=31&year=2016
```

A better approach though would be to make use of the `next` link on your page. For this the URL of the actual page would be needed. BeautifulSoup could then be used to easily extract the link.